# SSL sertificate crushes with AllowOverride all

Tags: https, subdomain, mod-rewrite

When I changed AllowOverride "none" to "all" in httpd.conf - my .htaccess file started to work, but my SSL dont want to work with that...

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Trying to get rid from www...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then I am getting an error in browsers

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
> information from website.com (for example, passwords, messages, or
> credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

All problem was in CNAME, I wrote there IP, but it have to be "website.com."